# Does container format conversion with FFmpeg involve any actual transcoding?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

If I convert between mp4, webm, and mkv with FFmpeg, will it cause possibly lossy transcoding, or is it just putting the same stuff into a new "container"? Would this possibly depend on what codec is inside the container?

Comment: **(1)** It depends on the codec. MP4 wants either H264 or H265 codecs. WebM wants either VP8 or VP9 codec and MKV can take any codec much like AVI or FLV or MOV (the reading side just needs to understand the provided video data). **(2)** If the MKV contains an H264 video codec then you can transfer that to MP4 without re-encoding.

Comment: @VC.One Thank you! That clarifies everything.

Answer (score 1):

See the comment @VC.One made on my original post. Incidentally, today I found out about the `-c copy` option. So what I will do in practice is attempt to use that option whenever converting between container formats, and if it works, I know there is no transcoding, and if it doesn't work, I know there is transcoding.